# CMake archive flag

Tags: cmake

I'm converting a c-shell script which builds some libraries and compiles some Fortran and C programs; it mostly works well (although I'm sure I'm not totally following correct conventions yet!).  However, I have one library which compile fine in the shell script, but not under CMake:

```
f95 -w -ffixed-line-length-132 -c mylib.for
ar cr myarchive.a mylib.o
```

generates the `.a` file. In my CMakeLists.txt I've got:

```
add_library(myarchive STATIC ${libsrc}/mylib.for)
```

I get 2 errors:

```
Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string at (1)
Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string at (1)
```

I can replicate this on the command line by not including the `-ffixed-line-length-132` flag, but I can't find how to include it in CMake.  The docs have got a `set(MAKE_LIBRARY_LINKER_FLAGS <STRING>)` command, which I've tried (and edited to `MAKE_ARCHIVE_LINKER_FLAGS`), and a `set_target_properties` - but there seems to be no definitive list of what the 3rd argument for this command can be.  There is meant to be a property called [`STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS`](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=629) but this doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the missing flag (`-ffixed-line-length-132`) is a *compiler flag* (you pass it to the `f95 -c` command in your example), you should set the compiler flags instead of the linker flags. I never used Fortran but I think the correct CMake variable is `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS`.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried setting `set(cmake_fortran_flags -ffixed-line-length-132)` both before and after the `add_library` call and get the same errors

Comment: @ChrisW: Just to be sure: did you use the correct capitalization? (`CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS`)

Comment: Oops! I thought that all CMake variables were case-insensitive (but I've just realised only command names are)! This works now :) I won't pretend to understand why it's a compile and not a link flag :/

Comment: @ChrisW: Well, you add the flag to the `f95` command which is the compiler. The `ar` command is the "linker" in case of a static library.